# How to export Syncfusion blazor pivot table and pivotchart in a single pdf page using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, pivot-table, visual-studio-2022, pivot-chart, syncfusion-blazor

I have a pivot table and pivotChart in a single razor page. I wanted to download both into a single file. I am using `ExportToPdfAsync` and `ExportToChartAsync` function to export the table and chart respectively. But now it is downloaded as 2 separate files. I want it to download as a single file.

While trying to use a filestream, the files are not stored anywhere, they are downloaded directly.